# graphQL query with variables (C#): what is the correct syntax for the query

Tags: c#, testing, graphql

I am writing a C# test using this client: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client.
Here is my query:

```
query getFilters($input: FilterInputType!) {
  getFilterData(input: $input) {
    assetId
    material
    productFamily
    equipmentModel
  }
}
```

And here are the query variables:

```
{
    "input": {
        "startDate": "2019-09-01T00:00:00",
        "endDate": "2019-09-30T23:59:59"
    }
}
```

When I execute the query in RestClient it returns data, but the query in the code does not work.
Here is my code:

```
var startDate = "2019-09-01T00:00:00";
var endDate = "2019-09-30T00:00:00";
var dateRange = new { startDate, endDate };
var getFiltersRequest2 = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = @"
                {                    
                    query getFilters($input: FilterInputType!) {
                      getFilterData(input: $input) {
                        assetId
                        material
                        productFamily
                        equipmentModel
                        sourceSite
                        destinationSite
                      }
                    }
                }",
    OperationName = "getFilters",
    Variables = new
    {
        input = dateRange
    }
};

//Act
GraphQLClient graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpointUrl);

graphQLClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
graphQLClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authToken);
var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.PostAsync(getFiltersRequest2);
```

What might be wrong with my syntax?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the outermost curly brackets in `Query`.